# 'Push Notification Permission' popup shows twice in iOS 11.1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios11

I have used push notification in my application. It works fine, but my problem is "push notification permission popup" appears twice in iOS 11.1.2. For lower versions it works fine.